# Not able to set null in SessionStorage

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html

I have used  `sessionStorage["collapseId"] = null` but it is not working. I don't know what's wrong. I haven't use it before. Pls help.

Comment: what browser? I can do this just fine in chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Session Storage is only capable of storing key/value pairs of **strings**. Then by trying:

```
sessionStorage["collapseId"] = null
```

What you're actually storing is a "null" string:

```
sessionStorage["collapseId"] === "null"
```

Try to `removeItem()` instead:

```
sessionStorage.removeItem('collapseId')
```

See [DOM Storage (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)

Answer (score 1):

In my scenario , I have set null value to `sessionStorage["IsNewData"]=null` and it's working fine , so can you plz provide a scenario  where you are stuck , and in other way you can also remove item from sessionStorage instead of set null like `sessionStorage.removeItem("IsNewData")`.